# 100% code-behind form post

Tags: asp.net, forms, webforms, linkbutton, form-post

I am looking for a way to wire up an ASP:LinkButton to appear as a link but in the background (100% in the code behind, no dummy pre-filled form in the markup) do a form post (target=_blank).  I have a form action, method and parameters to pass that I will query for in the "click" event of the LinkButton.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is multiple ways to read your question. Do you mean that you want to have a link on a page with no form at all (which you would need for a postback anyway) have server-side code decide what url to load when clicked in a popup window?

Comment: Server-side code will decide the URL, params, etc. all within the "click" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are LOTS of ways to do what i think you are trying to do :)

One problem; standard pop-up's don't fire event handler calls as they are mapped via post-back to the page i believe.

If you are happy with GET only submissions:

OPTION A:
Add your link button with no target set and setup a post back event handler for click

setup your URL and pass it back to the page into a JS function that will load right away eg  or use jquery etc.

in the JS function you load the URL using window.open() with the target set to "_blank"

EFFECT:
User clicks the link, all code is server-side that works out the URL to show, page refreshes back to where it was and a popup window then loads showing the new URL

OPTION B:
Setup the link to have target="_blank"

make it call a new page or the same page with a querystring argument you can pre-process in the page_load()

in the new page or controlling block of code, do your calculations and Response.Redirect() to the new target

EFFECT:
User clicks the link, no page refresh just a new popup right away with a redirect to the new page. This is a cleaner solution i think!

IF you need POST support:

Dynamically create either elements or a string of HTML representing a form with all the needed input elements and output it into the popup window (using option b as a rough start template) and have a onload submit the form right away which will perform a POST to the URL you decided via server-side script giving the same effect as option b but with a form level POST.